# instance.method is not a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I am quite new to javascript. So I just tried to create a simple object that draws two squares into the canvas. To understand object orientation a bit better I put them in different objects (where drawtest.js is the main). Unfortunately I dont see where my error lies. I have been searching posts on stackoverflow for hours, even the example from my prof looks (similiar) like mine, I don't see the difference but his version works. In firebug I get an:

**testobject.draw is not a function**

What did I forgot or made wrong?

"index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  

<head>  
<title>simple object test</title>
<script src="js/drawtest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/testobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>  

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>  

</body>  

</html>
```

the testfile "drawtest.js"

```
window.onload = function(){ init(); };

var canvas;
var context;

function init() 
{
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

testobject = new Test(context);

testobject.draw();  //this is where I get testobject.draw is not a function

}
```

the object "testobject.js"

```
function Test(context){

this.context = context;


Test.prototype=
{

draw:.
function()
{   
this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
this.context.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
this.context.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
}
};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

1. You have a syntax error:

   ```
   draw:.
   //   ^--- here
   ```

   Remove the dot. The syntax error should have shown up in the JavaScript/error console of whatever browser you're using. Kick around the menu system of your browser to find its developer tools; you'll want to get familiar with them. Chrome has quite a good set, recent versions of Firefox have them built in, older versions can use the Firebug plug-in.
2. It's best not to *replace* a constructor function's `prototype`; instead, just add to it:

   ```
   Test.prototype.draw = function() {   
       this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
       this.context.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

       this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
       this.context.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
   };
   ```
3. You don't want to make your `prototype` modifications *within* the constructor function, move that part outside the constructor function. So the `Test` function and its associated prototype properties becomes:

   ```
   function Test(context){

       this.context = context;
   }

   Test.prototype.draw = function() {   
       this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
       this.context.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

       this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
       this.context.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
   };
   ```

Comment: ah thank you very much, the syntax error was a mistake when copy paste to this site. but I will try your advises

Comment: There's nothing bad in replacing the whole prototype with your own object, when dealing with your own functions. I'd just recommend setting the constructor property back to the original one, so that you could later use instanceof if needed.

Comment: thank you very much that did the trick. I wonder why my professor didn't do it like this as well -__-

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa: There's a good reason for not replacing it: The wonderful world of hoisting. The `Test` function creation and the modification of its `prototype` happen at very different times. If you *replace* the `prototype`, it's possible to end up with some objects created with the blank one and others created with the new one. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/atifuv) Now, you'd never actually write code quite like that, but it's surprisingly easy to run into hoisting issues in large projects. (I actually define my constructor functions in a way to bypass hoisting, for this reason.)

Comment: The fact that certain use-cases can cause problems when replacing the object prototype, doesn't mean that you shouldn't use it altogether. For example, when setting up initial functions and inheritance, there's still nothing wrong with it, I'd even recommend it as the code is cleaner, shorter and more readable. If talking about functions that have already been instantiated, then yes, it's a really bad idea, but in 99% cases if you have to change the object prototype so radically after initiation, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Eddy63: As you're learning JavaScript, let me point you to a couple of useful resources: 1. [My own anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/), recommend starting with the oldest articles and working forward. 2. [Douglas Crockford's JavaScript articles](http://javascript.crockford.com/) - more advanced reading. Not everyone agrees with all of his arguments (I certainly don't), but everyone doing JS should read Crockford and make up their own minds. 3. [Mozilla's JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) 4. *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa: We'll have to agree to disagree. In my view, prototypes should be augmented, not replaced.

Comment: nice thanks for those resources. I have to finish a project until the end of January and barely know how javascript even works. the readings at the university haven't been very instructive, more like a crash course. same thing goes for python ( but it seems much easier then anything else). so every help and beginners-guides are appreciated. thx